# Applications Not Working Properly with Networked volumes

Tags: macos, network, smb, nfs, disk-volume

I have two applications from unrelated vendors which display a similar problem with networked volumes. I am using both of them with photos on a networked directory, but I don’t think that is the cause of the problem.

With one (Image Snooper), which searches for matching folders, if I search in the networked folder, I doesn’t even appear to look there, and finds no results. If I copy the folder onto the local disk and search there, it succeeds.

With the other (PhotoDirector 8), if I import a folder full of folders (full of photos) from a networked volume into a library (without copying), and then restart the application, it forgets the imported folders. Again, if I copy the folders onto the local disk and search there, it works properly.

I realise that different programs have different bugs, but it strikes me a significant that both applications fail on networked volumes.

I thought that the Operating System was supposed to handle the various mounted volumes as if they’re all the same, so an application should neither know nor care where the file is in reality, as long as it’s reachable.

The question is: do networked volumes get treated differently, and what can I do make them behave as local volumes?

I am running macOS Sierra and have tried mounting the volumes both as NFS and as SMB.

The server is a Linux server, less than 1 meter from my desktop, connected by Ethernet.

Comment: Can you tell us which applications you were having the problems with? Also, do you have a fast connection to the network storage? (is it closer to 5Mbps or 100Mbps)? Is the folder hosted on a NAS, an Apple device (Airport or Computer), or a Windows or Linux device? This will make it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @NoahL I’ve edit the question accordingly. The Applicaations are Image Snooper and PhotoDirector 8, and the server is Linux on a very close machine, connected by wire.